# Split Word-Document in seperate files

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a Python script that is supposed to create a Word document of 3015 pages into separate files. It should create a separate file for every 500 pages. Here I have a script that creates a Word document for 20 pages, but I don't know why it isn't taking 500.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import docx

# Get the path of the file to be split
file_to_split = "file.docx"

# Load the file to be split
doc = docx.Document(file_to_split)

# Get the page count of the file
total_pages = len(doc.paragraphs)

# Calculate the number of files to be created
total_files = total_pages//500 + 1

# Create the new files
for i in range(total_files):
    # Create the new file 
    new_doc = docx.Document()
    # Create the path of the file
    new_file_name = file_to_split[:-5] + "_" + str(i) + ".docx"
    # Set the start and end pages
    start_page = i * 500
    end_page = min((i+1)*500, total_pages)
    # Copy the content from the original file to the new file
    for j in range(start_page, end_page):
        new_doc.add_paragraph(doc.paragraphs[j].text)
    #Save the new file
    new_doc.save(new_file_name)

#Print the new files
print("The files have been successfully split.")
print("The new files are:")
for i in range(total_files):
    print(file_to_split[:-5] + "_" + str(i) + ".docx")
```

As I said, I expect that for each 500 pages from the original document, a new file will be created with the content up to page 500. After that, separate files should be created from 500-1000, 1000-1500, etc. The script mentioned above works, but 1. it takes a long time, and 2. separate files with a page count of 20 are created.